# How to restrict access to the profiler for test env in symfony

Tags: symfony

My test environment, while temporary, will give you the profiler by simply going to a non existent url. This is not okay.

**How can I restrict the web profiler to logged in users?**

I have tried

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: "^/_profiler", role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

but it makes no difference.  I assume because of the config

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

I am nervous to block the profiler function by accident.

I should add, I want to be able to access the profiler for debugging on the test env. not just turn it off.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the profiler to logged in users ? The profiler should just be used in a dev environment

Comment: my dev environment is local, so no problem everything wide open.  My test environment is online, a clone of the production env.  The test env will give me the profiler on error so I can debug it - it's rare but sometimes there are differences between what the production server has vs. my development server.  I don't want public access to the profiler but many people from around the world do testing.